# How to query this situation?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I wrote a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100093/what-other-queries-can-i-do-with-this-many-to-many-joining-table) a few hours ago about many to many queries. mellamokb suggested:

> How about list the categories, and how many posts in each category, sorted from the category with the most posts to the category with the least.

How do I actually make the query string? I can't even think where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO... Is this the sort of thing that you are looking for?

```
    SELECT category.name
         , COUNT(*) as [Count]
      FROM post
INNER JOIN postcategory ON post.id = postcategory.post_id
INNER JOIN category ON postcategory.category_id = category.id
  ORDER BY count
  GROUP BY category.name
```

Comment: yes! exactly! I just executed it and it works. Although..i don't understand how it works...let me study!